# eval() not working in WinJS. Disable WinJS.strictProcessing(); in Windows 8 store app

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a js code that I have used in my website. I have used a eval() to keep the code secret. But now I need to use the same code in my winJS app. But I found that the eval() function does not work in WIndows store app due to WinJS.strictProcessing() . By default it is turned on. So I need to turn it off . How could I do that. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "to keep the code secret" - a futile attempt. If it should be executed, it must be known.

Comment: Why just use non-secret code for your windows store app?

Comment: There is good reason eval is not used. It offers no security in terms of hiding source and represents one gigantic security hole just begging to be exploited. If there is one rule for JavaScript that should be followed, it is "NEVER EVER use eval!!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767331.aspx, which is part of the app host and not part of WinJS. You can do an eval within the callback you give to it. It's intentionally done this way to make you really, really conscious of how you're using functions like eval and the attendant security risks.

Comment: Has `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction` been deprecated in Edge?

Answer (score 0):

'WinJS.strictProcessing();' is a depreciated call. Strict processing is now always on. Sorry but eval has no place in the WinJS namespace.